# Java: UTF8 encoding is not displayed correctly in JTextArea

Tags: java, swing, character-encoding, java-io

I am trying to display txt or docx file content in JTextArea, but text area does not correcty display armenian or russian text. UTF-8 enconding in InputStreamReader does not help:

```
public class TextReader {

    public static String getText(File textFile) throws IOException {
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(textFile);
        InputStreamReader isr  = new InputStreamReader(fis, "UTF8");
        BufferedReader br  = new BufferedReader(isr);
        StringBuilder text = new StringBuilder();

        String c;

        while ((c = br.readLine()) != null)
            text.append(c + "\n");

        fis.close();
        isr.close();
        br.close();

        return String.valueOf(text);
    }

}
```

I am using this static method in another class in JTextArea:

```
        String text = TextReader.getText(currentFile);
        textArea.setText(text);
```

After running and choosing the file, I got random characters. What could be the solution in this case?

Comment: Use debug to verify that the text is not corrupted by the Reader. Check the font used by the JTextArea. It may be that the font does not support those characters.

Comment: also, is the source file actually utf-8 encoded?

Comment: I've added universalchardet in TextReader class for charset atuo-detection and it helped. Also, i've added setFont method for textArea, so it will get correct encoding from TextReader class and use it.

Comment: By the way, which Java version are you using? In Java 8, you may just use `return Files.lines(textFile.toPath()).collect(Collectors.joining("\n"));` In Java 11, you can use `return Files.readString(textFile.toPath());` to read the entire file in one go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code seems to be fine. My guess is you are trying to read a `docx` file.

You can't directly read `docx` files this way. Use some library like [Apache POI](https://poi.apache.org/).

If you are indeed using a text file, it might be the case that application you use to save the file uses wrong encoding. You could try saving some (hard-coded) sample Russian text using Java itself to a text file and reading it again in to your `JTextArea`.

Comment: Yes, the file was really wrong encoded. So i added universalchardet functionality to class, to not depend on the file encoding. For word files i will use Apache POI, thanks!